# C++ strange access violation Visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm really puzzled by this error I don't know if it's a C++ problem, OpenCV, an IDE problem or lack of knowledge. I'm using VS2015 RC, OpenCV 2.4.10. 
This is my code

```
void cluster(cv::Mat &im)
{
cv::Mat thresholded = im.clone();
threshold(im, thresholded, 254, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

// Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.filterByCircularity = false;
params.filterByInertia = false;
params.filterByColor = false;

// Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 200;
params.maxThreshold = 250;

// Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 50;

// Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = true;
params.minConvexity = 0;
params.maxConvexity = 1;

// Set up the detector with default parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);


// Detect blobs.
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

detector.detect(thresholded, keypoints);
}
```

When I run this code every line is executed fine, but at the end of the function I get the following error

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAC07A51EA (ntdll.dll) in OP4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAC07A51EA (ntdll.dll) in OP4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

The problem doesn't appear if I initialized SimpleBlobDetector with the default constructor. I checked the return of the detect function and it returns the correct value, I even plotted it. But the error appears when the function ends. I tried increasing the stack size as well. I also tried to have it in the main function, and it eventually gives an access violation !!

Help please!

Comment: Are you sure that your calling conventions are correct and you aren't overrunning any stack buffers?  Typically, when a function access violates upon return, my first instinct is to check for possible stack corruption.  Have you tried watching up to the ret instruction?  When you get to that ret, check the value referenced by the stack pointer.  The value should be the address after the call that invoked this function, if its anything else (i.e -1) you may be corrupting the stack somehow.

Comment: But does it make sense that it works perfectly fine if I used the default constructor of the SimpleBlobDetector! Given the code you see, can I be corrupting the stack buffer by any means?

Comment: Not that I can tell, also, I'm probably wrong about the return address being wrong, since the error says 'reading' instead of executing.  My next guess would be something in the destructor of either the SimpleBlobDetector or the SimpleBlobParams.  What does the stack trace look like in a debugger?  What function is getting called in ntdll?

Comment: You're probably right, it first tried to deallocate cv:KeyPoint then operator delete(void * block). After that are errors from ucrtbased.dll and ntdll.dll

Comment: @superultranova - Surely the computer has to _load_ code before it can execute it. Anyway, in my experience, weird unexplainable errors like this are often attributable to incompatible dynamic libraries (ie DLLs). I would suggest making sure you're linking against the right version of the libraries and then doing a _clean_ build (ie, select "Clean Solution" from the Build menu, then "Build Solution" once the clean is done).

Comment: @celticminstrel, I don't know what you're talking about.  Of course the code is loaded, I'm just wondering if during destruction something is going wrong, since the error is happening upon return from the function.

Comment: For example, if you're using some DLLs, and you build your project, but then you update to a new version of those DLLs, you can often get strange errors that are fixed by completely rebuilding like I described. Whether that's the issue here, I'm not sure.

Comment: @celticminstrel sure, using out of date builds could definitely cause issues.  I was confused by your code loading comment.  I still think that it would be best to see what the issue is in a debugger.  Just because the error isn't causing the program to crash, doesn't mean it isn't there anymore.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the code loading comment was one thing, and the rest of my comment was something completely unrelated aimed at the original poster. I meant that the computer needs to load the code into memory (well, more like from memory into a register) before attempting to execute it, so if you _did_ somehow jump the execution pointer to an inaccessible memory location, you'd probably get access violation errors.

Comment: @celticminstrel code isn't typically loaded into a register, at least not on x86.  Its very easy to cause the instruction pointer to an invalid memory location by causing misalignment in the stack (calling convention error etc) or by overwriting the return address (buffer overflow).  Its probably not the issue in this case though.  And you're right, if you try to set EIP to 0xFFFFFFFF, you'll almost certainly get an access violation.

Comment: @PokaYoke I'm having the same issue, but with ucrtbased.dll.  Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Erutan409 my solution was more of a work around, the problem was in VS2015 RC's development environment I guess; so I copied the source files and created a new solution over a more robust IDE VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a problem with VS2015 RC, I created a new project using exactly the same code on VS2010 and it works like charm !

Comment: When you tested with VS 2015 was your OpenCV 2.4.10 dlls built with Visual Studio 2015 also?

Comment: No, prebuilt libraries. But I have been developing using VS 2015 on this project for a while and all of the OpenCV functionalities were working just fine. That's why the issue was puzzling.